# Check Constraint not firing correctly

Tags: sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong, as this is my first check constraint, but I can't understand why it's not working. I need to check that a date range doesn't overlap.

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_DateOverlaps (@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE, @ProjectID INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret BIT
    SET @Ret = 1

   IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM project_sprint
        WHERE ((@StartDate >= StartDate AND @EndDate <= EndDate)
        OR (@StartDate <= StartDate AND @EndDate >= EndDate))
        AND ProjectId = @ProjectId
        ) 
    BEGIN
        SET @Ret = 0
    END
    RETURN @Ret
END
GO
```

I then apply this to my table:

```
ALTER TABLE Project_Sprint WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_DateOverlaps CHECK (dbo.fn_DateOverlaps([StartDate], [EndDate], [ProjectId])=1)
GO
```

When I test the function, I get a good result:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_DateOverlaps('2013-06-10', '2013-06-13', 1)
```

But then when I apply the same date range and project ID to my table, it allows the insert. It should fail it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you change `SELECT * FROM project_sprint` to `SELECT * FROM dbo.project_sprint` the function will correctly evaluate, **but** you won't get the desired behavior, since the value you are inserting or editing will lead to an unwanted find.
To prevent this you will have to add an additional ID field to except the row you want to edit/insert for the check.

```
Create Table Project_Sprint(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,ProjectID int,StartDate DateTime,EndDate DateTime)

go


Alter FUNCTION fn_DateOverlaps (@ID int,@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE, @ProjectID INT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret BIT
    SET @Ret = 0

   IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM dbo.project_sprint
        WHERE
        @ID<>ID AND
         ((@StartDate >= StartDate AND @EndDate <= EndDate)
        OR (@StartDate <= StartDate AND @EndDate >= EndDate))
        AND ProjectId = @ProjectId
        ) 
    BEGIN
        SET @Ret = 1
    END
    RETURN @Ret
END
GO
ALTER TABLE Project_Sprint  ADD CONSTRAINT ck_DateOverlaps CHECK (dbo.fn_DateOverlaps([ID],[StartDate], [EndDate], [ProjectId])=1)
```